# Force Laravel model to check ownership before fetching

Tags: laravel

I am unsure how to accomplish this, but I would like to have either a middleware, trait or whatever that would force an ownership check on specified models. For instance, I would like to do this:

```
Posts::all()
```

But instead of getting all posts, I would like to get only the posts of the current logged user. Of course I could add a `::where(['user_id' => auth()->user()->id])` but I would like to manage that on a lower, more secure level.

Basically, I would like to force this where condition in my model, if possible.

Comment: Have you tried a Global Scope? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#global-scopes; you'd be able to define a scope that checks if a User is authenticated and applies that `where()` clause accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to write a [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#query-scopes) for your model class.

For instance (in `Post.php`):

```php
    /**
     * Example usage:
     * Post::ownedByCurrentUser()->get();
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeOwnedByCurrentUser($query) {
        return $query->where([
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        ]);
    } // end scopeOwnedByCurrentUser()
```

You could go a step further and make this more flexible with a separate scope allowing you to query ANY user's posts:

```php
    /**
     * Example usage:
     * // get all posts belonging to a user
     * Post::owner(auth()->user()->id)->get();
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @param int $userId User ID of owner
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeOwner($query, int $userId) {
        return $query->where([
            'user_id' => $userId,
        ]);
    } // end scopeOwner()
```

They're flexible since you can add extra query bits after them:

```php
Post::owner(1234)->orderBy('date')->whereModified(null); // etc
```

Use your imagination. :-)

Comment: Thanks my fellow laraveler!